# Should I use `Express` and `Socket.IO` separately?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, load-balancing

For example we have this simple code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

When `/` is loaded and `start` button pressed via `socket.io` request sent which starts on back-end heavy stuff (lot of different http requests which could be from 5 to 10 sec) and when response comes it immediately are throw back to the browser.

So the main question: should I split the app in to two pieces?

1. back-end with `Socket.IO` as one process
2. front-end with `Express` as second process

I'm aware that when the long requests comes it will block `Express`. For example when one user do search for others site will be down while long requests are in progress.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a definitive answer about one vs. two processes by fully understanding and probably profiling/testing your actual code and clients.  If your node.js code (whether regular http requests or socket.io requests) is properly using non-blocking I/O and is not CPU intensive, then you can field a surprisingly high number of requests with a single process.  That is a primary advantage of the node.js architecture.

If, on the other hand, you have some heavy CPU-intensive calculation as part of most requests, then you may indeed want to cluster your whole app.  I would recommend clustering over splitting socket.io from http because that gives you multiple CPUs to work on either your socket.io requests or your http requests.